# How to run a python script when geometry nodes group input changed

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes

Is there any way to run a python script the moment that the user changes a value of a specific input in geometry nodes group? for example a Boolean input.

Comment: You can create a custom handler that fires everytime the scene changes and using if statement check whether the change happend in the specific node you want. You'll probably have to keep track of the value of this node so that you can compare it with a new one and decide whether the change really happened or was just prompted and then canceled (the handler will fire in both cases)

Comment: I've never used it but this might help: If you have Python Tooltips checked under Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display and hover over the required input field on the Geometry Node modifier panel it will show you the python code for that option. Note that the ["Input x"] at the end of the bpy string doesn't seem to bear any relationship to the order of the inputs in the list!